# Lost iPhone but someone is trying to use it - how can I track this

Tags: iphone

My iPhone was stolen and I have blocked it, recently I received an email stating that I reported a problem... Someone is obviously trying to use my phone but because they can not access the internet or wifi I am unable to track this, does anyone know how I can track my phone?

Comment: Did you have find my iphone enabled?

Answer (score 1):

If you have Find My iPhone enabled, simply log on to icloud.com and log in with your iTunes username and password. From the Find My iPhone home page, you can remotely wipe your phone or send a message to the thief. If you don't have Find My iPhone, try contacting your service provider to see if they can get a lock on the phone's location.